# save value from intercepted body using cypress

Tags: cypress, e2e-testing

I have the following code:

```
let test="not-set";
cy.intercept(
    {
        url: '**/consumers/rx?extension=.jpg',
        method:"POST"
    },
    (req) => {
        req.on('response', (res) => {
            // cy.log(res.body.rxId);
            expect(res.body.rxId).not.to.be.null;
            test = res.body.rxId;
            // cy.wrap(res.body.rxId).as('rxId')
        })
    }
)
cy.log(test); // the value will be not-set
```

How could I save/use the value `res.body.id` in the follwing test steps

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way:

```
cy.intercept(
{
    url: '**/consumers/rx?extension=.jpg',
    method:"POST"
},
(req) => {
    req.on('response', (res) => {
        expect(res.body.rxId).not.to.be.null;
    })
}).as('myIntercept');

//trigger request

cy.wait('@myIntercept')
  .its('response')
  .then(response=> {
     cy.wrap(response.body.id).as('id');
  })
//blabla
cy.get('@id').then(console.log);
```